# How do I LaTeX print sympy objects from within loops

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to LaTeX print objects from within loops or list comprehensions with a line break between each element.

```
x, y = symbols('x y')
t = [x, y]
# pprint gives a line break
[pprint(i) for i in t]
# print gives a syntax error as it is a statement
[print(i) for i in t]
# Without a print function it just returns the list horizontally.
[i for i in t]
```

I guess there might just be a function to replace in for pprint(i).

Comment: Why are you printing in a comprehension? Just write a loop.

Comment: Wasn't that the whole promise of making print a function in Python 3, that we could print in comprehensions?

Comment: You should add `import sympy` or `from sympy import init_session; init_session()` so that it is clear that a SymPy environment has been started.

Answer (score 0):

`pprint` is not LaTeX, but that's a separate point.

`pprint` is just a wrapper around `pretty_print` that prints it. If you want to control the printing, use `pretty_print` directly, like

```
for i in t:
    print pretty_print(i),
```

The comma at the end will suppress the newline. Or, in Python 3 or with `from __future__ import print_function`:

```
for i in t:
    print(pretty_print(i), end=' ')
```

(and with that, you can even do it in a comprehension if you want).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain this well. I DO want the LaTeX output rather than the pretty ASCII. I was using pprint as an example of something that did work, but wasn't quite what I wanted.

Comment: Do you want the LaTeX text or pretty LaTeX output in the IPython notebook?

Comment: There is a `sympy.pprint` that is imported into the main name space by starting a SymPy session with `from sympy import init_session; init_session()`.

Comment: Or just `from sympy import pretty_print`.

Answer (score 0):

I accidently SOLVED this problem when reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62237257/force-sympy-to-print-math-in-mathjax-jupyter) :

```
from IPython.display import display  
from sympy import init_session

init_session()  
for i in range(1,5):  
  display(series(coth(x), x=x, x0=0, n=i)
```

* [update dynamically](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-dynamically-update-a-plot-in-a-loop-in-ipython-notebook)